# Including .h files for functions

Tags: c

I am passing a struct pointer to a function in another .c file. Do I need to include this header file in both .c files?

```
//test.h
typedef struct {
   int number;

} STATS;

//test.c
#include "test.h"
void function(){

   func2(s);
}

//stats.c
//do I need : include "test.h"
void func2(STATS * ptr){
    ptr->number = 10;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Once to make sure the definition matches the declaration, and once (or many times) so that the code that uses the function knows how it is declared.  The header keeps everything in sync — it is very important, therefore.  Note that the function `func2()` should be declared in the header too, with a full prototype.  Also, it isn't clear how `s` comes into things — neither the declaration nor the definition is shown.

Comment: If you do not include `test.h` in stats.c, I would expect the compiler to complain since it will have no idea what `STATS` is.

Comment: Yes, you need the test.h as  STATS is not defined in stats.c

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `stats.c` needs the structure definition in order to know where the `num` member is in the `STATS` structure.

If it were simply passing the pointer along to some other function, it wouldn't need the structure definition; you would just need a forward declaration of the structure type name; all structure pointers are required to be compatible this way, and that allows the pointer to be treated as an opaque handle. But since `func2` accesses a member, it's not opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to instantiate the struct class because u declared the number variable in .h class